# How to know the deployment status of multiple release pipelines in Azure DevOps at one place

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I have multiple build and release pipelines in Azure DevOps. I have created Dashboard in Azure DevOps to know the build and release status of each pipeline using “Deployment Status” & “Release Pipeline Overview” widgets.

But I want to monitor the multiple release pipelines status in single widget.

Answer (score 0):

> How to know the deployment status of multiple release pipelines in Azure DevOps at one place

I am afraid that there are no out-of-the-box widgets to display the deployment status of multiple release pipelines at one place on the azure devops dashboard.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site ([https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21%C2%A0) ), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Is there any custom approach to do it?

Comment: @Pradeep, AFAIK, There doesn't seem to be such a custom approach at the moment.